# Heroku time vs Local time : too much difference

Tags: java, performance, heroku, optimization, client-server

When running spring boot application in local I can see that the time between my server and client is :

```
2018-04-08 19:13:26.030  INFO 20348 --- [nio-9191-exec-4] c.pmdcodereview.algo.MetadataLoginUtil   : Total Time Taken 9346
2018-04-08 19:13:26.035  INFO 20348 --- [nio-9191-exec-4] c.p.controller.PMDController             : Total Time Taken from PMDController 4
```

but as soon as I host the app in heroku, this changes to :

```
2018-04-08T14:09:28.807136+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-04-08 14:09:28.806  INFO 4 --- [o-38031-exec-10] c.pmdcodereview.algo.MetadataLoginUtil   : Total Time Taken 77740
2018-04-08T14:09:28.846032+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-04-08 14:09:28.845  INFO 4 --- [o-38031-exec-10] c.p.controller.PMDController             : Total Time Taken from PMDController 38
```

How is this even possible, I have tried hosting my app in ngrok, to see if exposing my app to internet may be similar to heroku, but even ngrok shows :

```
 2018-04-08 19:07:10.931  INFO 20348 --- [nio-9191-exec-6] c.pmdcodereview.algo.MetadataLoginUtil   : Total Time Taken 9487
 2018-04-08 19:07:10.936  INFO 20348 --- [nio-9191-exec-6] c.p.controller.PMDController             : Total Time Taken from PMDController 5
```

How do I handle this issue? 
I have tried every optimization possible from server side to give a quick response to client, but still it fails in heroku? 
I am using free dyno in heroku.

Comment: Is there a difference between the first request to Heroku and the second? Heroku will put a Free app to sleep when no requests are being sent, so you have overhead to wake it up the first time.

Comment: Nope, I always see the heroku logs, I only send the request after the Spring boot has fully started.

Comment: What is the process doing? Is it CPU intensive, or IO intensive? A Free Heroku dyno is *much* less powerful than your laptop, so it may just take longer.

Comment: I think that might be the issue, my operation is CPU intensive because I have verified it with visual VM and have seen a CPU spike when the loop runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Free Heroku dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types#available-dyno-types) use a shared CPU, which means a CPU bound process will likely be slower on a Heroku dyno than on an expensive laptop.

Another common cause (though probably not in this case) is that Heroku will put idle Free dynos to sleep, which means they must pay the startup overhead on the next request.

Comment: I have written an async method to overcome this, but the issue is that the async request should keep on checking if the request has been completed, I tried to recursively call the method, but the full url gets hit and whole process starts again. How to implement this, any idea.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726559/spring-boot-async-request-not-returning-anything

I have been struggling for this.

Comment: sorry, i don't know enough about Spring to help there. You might want to start a new post for that question (to get better visibility)