# Spring boot : Async request not returning anything

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, heroku

Js :

```
$('#loaderImage').show();

$http.get('/utilities/longProcess')
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('Completed');
        $scope.sampleJSON = data.pmdStructureWrapper;
        $scope.sampleJSONDuplicates = data.pmdDuplicates;
        $scope.$watch('sampleJSON', setTimeout(function() {
            $('.panel-body li').each(function() {
                if ($.trim($(this).text()) === "") {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        }, 1000));
        $('#loaderImage').hide();
    })
    .error(function(data, status, header, config) {

    });
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/utilities/longProcess")
    public DeferredResult<String> async(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
        DeferredResult<String> dr = new DeferredResult<>();
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return callURL(response, request);
        }, ex).thenAccept((String message) -> {
            dr.setResult(message);
        });
        return dr;
    }

private String callURL(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
    PMDMainWrapper pmdMainWrapper = new PMDMainWrapper();
    Map<String, PMDStructureWrapper> codeReviewByClass = new HashMap<>();
    String partnerURL = this.partnerURL;
    String toolingURL = this.toolingURL;
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    List<PMDStructure> violationStructure = null;
    try {
        violationStructure = metadataLoginUtil.startReviewer(partnerURL, toolingURL, cookies);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PMDStructureWrapper pmdStructureWrapper = null;
    List<PMDStructure> pmdStructureList = null;
    List<PMDStructure> pmdDuplicatesList = new ArrayList<>();
    int size = violationStructure.size();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (codeReviewByClass.containsKey(violationStructure.get(i).getName())) {
            PMDStructureWrapper pmdStructureWrapper1 = codeReviewByClass.get(violationStructure.get(i).getName());
            List<PMDStructure> pmdStructures = pmdStructureWrapper1.getPmdStructures();
            pmdStructures.add(violationStructure.get(i));
            pmdStructureWrapper1.setPmdStructures(pmdStructures);

        } else {
            pmdStructureList = new ArrayList<>();
            pmdStructureList.add(violationStructure.get(i));
            pmdStructureWrapper = new PMDStructureWrapper();
            pmdStructureWrapper.setPmdStructures(pmdStructureList);
            codeReviewByClass.put(violationStructure.get(i).getName(), pmdStructureWrapper);
        }
    }

    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();

    LOGGER.info("Total Time Taken from PMDController "+  String.valueOf(stop-start));
    if (!codeReviewByClass.isEmpty()) {
        pmdMainWrapper.setPmdStructureWrapper(codeReviewByClass);
        pmdMainWrapper.setPmdDuplicates(pmdDuplicatesList);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        return gson.toJson(pmdMainWrapper);
    }

    return "";
}
```

I am going with async process because when the app is hosted in heroku, it takes almost 120 seconds to return the result to the page, but as per heroku documentation the rest api should return within 30 seconds otherwise it terminates the process,

But still after implementing the above logic I am seeing the timeout error.
I have kept a console log in the javascript `console.log('Completed');` but that gets printed only when it returns the result from `callURL` method which is taking more than 120 seconds to return.

What i wanted to implement is when the UI sends a request, it should keep receiving a message which says still loading, so that the request does not gets timeedout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` runs the specified supplier in a different thread (one from the `ForkJoinThreadPool` for default). `thenAccept()` method only runs after the previous execution returns. So, it won't return fast in your case, you're just calling the long running call in a different thread.

Instead, define a common object, which acts as a cache (such as `HttpSession`), and make the `CompletableFuture` return the object stored there. And execute `callURL()`only when the cache is empty:

```
@RequestMapping("/utilities/longProcess")
public CompletableFuture<String> async(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> session.getAttribute("CACHED_RESULT"))
            .thenComposeAsync(obj -> {
                if (obj == null) {
                    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> callUrl(request, response))
                            .thenAccept(result -> session.setAttribute("CACHED_RESULT", result));
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("not ready yet");
                }
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(obj.toString());
            });
```

You can also add a timestamp to see when you did the last call to `callUrl()` and don't call `callUrl()` again when you've made a call but not received the answer yet.

Comment: wont this block the UI until the result has been shared to UI.

Comment: If the result isn't ready yet, client will get `"not ready yet"` response without waiting. Else, the result is ready in the cache and it will be returned immediately.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly fine, the only thing is to show the loader screen until the job completes, that I will figure it out.

Comment: What if after the request comes in, the user refreshes the page, wont that trigger the callUrl method again?

Comment: Yes, it will. That's why you might consider putting a timestamp in the session, as I suggested in the answer.